# Find most discussed topics from a set of topics (a column in the table)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database column `topics` with datatype `nvarchar`. I have to search in these records to find the "TRENDING TOPICS" and display them.

By "TRENDING TOPICS", I mean to say that I want to get the most discussed topic. For example, from the feed titles in twitter, I need to select the most discussed topic and the count of it.

How to approach this? Pls help..

Edit:

I have 4 records in the table as:

```
1 - Aenean at enim lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
2 - Morbi nulla diam, fermentum ullamcorper commodo blandit
3 - Quisque a sapien mi, ac congue orci
4 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

I have to find the most discussed topic from these rows. For example: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet` comes in records 1 & 4. So, this is the most discussed topic. Likewise from thousands of rows, I need to find 5 mostly discussed topic. The topic could be a single word too.

Note: I am not giving any input to the query.

Is there any way I could attain the purpose (even with Analysis Services(SSAS))?

Answer (score 1):

You're not very clear with your question - can you possibly provide some examples of what may be stored in your `topics` column??

I'm guessing this query alone won't solve your problem:

```
SELECT topics, COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY topics
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: @SunilRaj: so you basically want to have the frequency of every single word or combination of any number of words, from thousands of rows? hmm .....